# jQuery slideToggle issue with captions in Wordpress and flexslider

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using Flexslider for Wordpress and want to slideToggle the captions for each image in a flexslider slidshow.

Here is an example of a slideshow:
http://lifescienceaurora.com/news/cu-anschutz/cu-anschutz-news/ranking-file/

Click the "plus" in the upper left corner.

Here's the issue:
After clicking the "+" twice to show and hide the caption of the current image,
the next slide shows its caption.

I need for all captions to be hidden until clicking on the toggle button.

Here's my code: (I've updated it to reflect "flexslider's rendered code")

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.flex-caption').hide();
    $('.flexslider').append('<button class="captionToggle">+</button>');

    $('.flexslider button').click(function(){
        $('.flex-caption').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

And here an example of the HTML

```
<div id="smg_1" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li><img src="image1.jpg"/>
    <p class="flex-caption">caption1 here</p>
    <button class="captionToggle">+</button>
</li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg"/>
    <p class="flex-caption">caption2 here</p>
    <button class="captionToggle">+</button>
</li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg"/>
    <p class="flex-caption">caption3 here</p>
    <button class="captionToggle">+</button>
</li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg"/>
    <p class="flex-caption">caption4 here</p>
    <button class="captionToggle">+</button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My understanding of jQuery is from example only so I don't have the tools to troubleshoot this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest providing the HTML/CSS as well if any.  I normally would just hide it using CSS then use slideToggle to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using `.stop()` or `.stop(1)` to clear previous animations queue:

`$('span.wp-caption-text').stop(1).slideToggle('slow');`

and related to your issue try with:

```
$('.wp-caption button').click(function(){
    $('span.wp-caption-text').is(':visible').hide(); // hide all already visible captions
    $('span.wp-caption-text').stop(1).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What it sounds like is you're missing the event to close it every time a new slide appears.  I would suggest running `$('.wp-caption-text').hide();` every time your slide loads/activates.

I have not used flexslider, but this is based on the API I found.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
       before: function () {
            $('.flex-caption').hide();
       }
   });
});
```

Update: this will slide toggle only the button li that you have open.  However, it will not close the caption between slides.

```
 $('.flexslider ul.slides li button').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: What's happening is once the click is initiated on the first slide the rest of the slide captions change to "display:block" (using web inspector)

Comment: I updated the code because the button was being rendered twice in each <li> element. Captions in the hidden slides are still being changed to display:block

Comment: Its a little difficult to play with when I don't have much, but I updated the code so it will select the image.  Is it possible for you to show me your code implementation in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?